# How do i set the id in WinJS.Binding.Template in a Win8 App

Tags: windows-8, winjs

The following html is not working for me.

```
<div id="weightListViewTemplate"  data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
<span  data-win-bind="innerText: name; id: id"></span>
</div>

<div id="basicListView" style="width:420px;height:600px"  data-win-options="{ itemTemplate: select('#weightListViewTemplate') }"
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView">
</div>
```

The list appears but the ID property is not set on the span objects.

How to a set the id of the span dynamically in the template based on the corresponding value in the datasource/array?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the actual ID property. I believe you can't set it through data binding -- I believe WinJS uses ID's on elements under the covers to allow for weak-references to the DOM elements. Because of this it doesn't let you set the ID.

I would suggest using another property or attribute instead.

Comment: Dominic is correct - binding explicitly does NOT let you set the id property. If you're using binding, you should be manipulating the DOM by changing the data you're bound to, not by looking up the expansions in the DOM.

Comment: @ChrisTavares Just curious, what is the alternative to quickly access an item without looping through the items to find `item.someProperty === someValue` if we are not using `id`?

Comment: For the DOM, this won't help you anyway -- you could easy have a name clash unless your using some global ID generator. If you wish to find the element, you're gonna have to add a class, attribute, or other property to querySelector for.

Comment: @DominicHopton Thx for the reply. I actually wonder whether assigning the unique property of the item is a good idea. E.g. `item.id = SSN` Then I can do fast retrieval of that item by `SSN`. Any drawbacks on this?

Comment: I never really found query selector to be that expensive; especially from a subtree. I mean, are you calling this in a tight loop? If so, cache the item before you enter the loop & capture it in a closure. Not saying "no", but I think a little more on the actual need might help