# How can I set an ID in data-win-bind?

Tags: javascript, css, windows, html, winjs

I'm having a big trouble with the template of W8:

```
    <div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
        <div class="item-overlay">
            <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 291.08px;"></h4>
            <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But some items I need that they have a different look and I need to add them an ID for example this code is in the data.js:

```
        var sampleItems = [
        { group: sampleGroups[0], importancia: "top", title: "Item Title: 1", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: lightGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 2", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 2", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: darkGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 3", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 3", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: mediumGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 4", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 4", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: darkGray },
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 5", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 5", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: mediumGray }];
```

How can I add the IDs?, because the option *importancia* determines me which one have IDs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i set the id in WinJS.Binding.Template in a Win8 App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620411/how-do-i-set-the-id-in-winjs-binding-template-in-a-win8-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `dynamic template binding` to assign values to the `id` attribute to the `ListView` items. Though, notice that in the "potential duplicate" that @DominicHopton pointed out, you may not want to assign an `id` to your items.

```
function listViewItemTemplate(item) {
    // data has has information about each item
    var data = item.data._value;

    var itemElement = document.createElement('div');
    if (data.shouldHaveId) { // check whatever condition that you need
        itemElement.id = data.id; // assign an id to your element
    }

    ...

    return {element: itemElement}
}

...

// Then you can assign the template to your listview
youListViewControl.itemTemplate = listViewItemTemplate;
```